I am having issues with the output of my basic C program to print area of a circle
i am a beginner at C programming and I was trying out a basic function to produce the area of a circle. the radius had to be taken as input from the user. the code is as follows :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float areacircle(float r);
float area;
float r;

int main() {
    printf("enter the radius of the circle: ");
    scanf("%f", r);
    areacircle(r);
    return 0;
}


float areacircle(float r) {
    area = 3.14 * r * r;
    printf("the area of the circle is : %f", area);
}

whenever the user enters any radius, the output is always 0.00. why is this happening ? the output should show the area of the circle according to the radius which has been entered.

scanf("%f",&r); - you have to use a pointer for scanf

Welcome to SO. This is a good point to start learning debugging. Start your code in your debugger and what your variables change. If they change differently from what you expect, you know where to look closer. Also read your compiler warnings. if you did not get a warning for wrong type of argument for %f format specifier, turn up yur warning level. For GCC you can use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic. Then read and solve all warnings before you try to run the program. Do not ignore any warning unless you really understand what they mean.

Is there a specific reason why you use float type? That type has less precision than double type. Unless you are really limited on memory, you should always use double instead of float.

You could also make areacircle generic so that it can be used with float, double or long double with the appropriate value for PI. Example including fixes for the issues pointed out in the answer by wohlstad.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings

This example is an excellent demonstration that beginners should never use scanf.  Do not waste your time with scanf.  It will lead you down many wrong paths and cause you to spend a lot of time figuring out its foibles, and all of that time is completely wasted.  For this simple example, the radius should be passed as an argument to main.  Eventually, you will need to learn how to read data from a stream, but for now that is just distracting you from learning the language.

There are several things you can learn from the answer and the comments. Most important is to learn about 1) compiler options and 2) compiler warnings. You need to know the compiler options for getting a high warning level. And you need to learn that you never ignore warnings. Don't even try to run a program if there are any warnings. For the gcc compiler use options like -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic.

You do not need a pointer for scanf, you need an address.  A pointer is not an address.  A pointer is a variable, and the value that it stores is an address (or "memory location").  For some reason, pointers cause a lot of confusion, and I suspect much of that confusion stems from failing to distinguish between the words "address" and "pointer".

Welcome to StackOverflow @TishyaMisra. If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. With enough rep you can also upvote any helpful answer (voting and accepting is separate). See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

scanf requires the address of each argument, in order to update it (if scanf would have accepted arguments by value, it could not have updated them for the caller).
Therefore:
scanf("%f",r);

Should be:
scanf("%f",&r);

Also always check the return value of scanf to make sure it succeeded.
scanf returns:

Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned

Therefore it should return 1 in this case.
Another problem in you code is that areacircle is supposed to return a float value, but in fact does not return anything.
If you want it to just print the result, change the return value to void. Alternatively return the proper value, and use it in main.
Lastly, there is no need to use global variables for r and area. It is better to use local ones.
